# Spring Security always redirecting me to the default login page

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, request

**Issue**

So I am using Spring boot as backend and React JS as frontend. My **Issue** is that I am always getting **redirect** to `http://localhost:8080/login` if the authentication is **successful**. This is the default login page. In my security class I have **configured** that it will redirect to `http://localhost:8080/authenticated` if authentication is **successful** and if it **fails** then redirect to `http://localhost:8080/notauthenticated`. If I type **wrong** username and password it works. It redirects me to `http://localhost:8080/notauthenticated` but if I type the **correct** username and password it always redirects me to `http://localhost:8080/login` but I get a sessionid that **works**. If I type wrong credentials I also get a sessionid but this sessionid **doesn't work** which make sense.
`/authenticated` and `/notauthenticated` are just 2 Endpoints that just return a ResponseEntity with a type of Boolean.
I also don't understand why it doesn't return true or false. In postman I get true if I'm authenticated but if not then it redirects me to the default login page.

**Code**

Spring Security Config Class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "PUT")
                .allowedHeaders("Content-Type", "X-Requested-With", "accept", "Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method",
                        "Access-Control-Request-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Method", "Set-Cookie")
                .exposedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials")
                .allowCredentials(true).maxAge(3600);
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/", "index", "/css/*", "/js/*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/authenticated", true)
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .failureUrl("/notauthenticated")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/perform_logout")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

}
```

The 2 Endpoints:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticated", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> authenticate(){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(true, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/notauthenticated", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> notAuthenticate(){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(false, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

The submit function in reactjs looks like this:

```
   handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { username, password } = this.state;
    try {
      let res = await Axios({
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
        },
        url: "/perform_login",
        data: "username=" + username + "&password=" + password
      });
      let redirectUrl = await res.request.responseURL;
      console.log(res);
      console.log(redirectUrl);
      if(redirectUrl !== 'http://localhost:8080/notauthenticated'){

      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem and I solved by adding this annotation to my SpringWebApplication class, this specify to Spring to remove default configuration

```
@ComponentScan( { "it.myapplication.controllers" } )
@EnableCaching
@SpringBootApplication( exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class } )
public class MyWebApplication{
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        SpringApplication.run( MyWebApplication.class, args );
    }
}
```

In my WebSecurityConfig class I didn't change nothing

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception
    {

    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers( "/","/home") 
            .permitAll() 
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and()
            .formLogin().loginPage( "/login" )
            .permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();
    }
```

And I created a simple login.html page under resources/templates containing the login form. I'm using thymeleaf as template engine.

```
 <body>
    <div th:if="${param.error}">
        Invalid username and password.
    </div>
    <div th:if="${param.logout}">
        You have been logged out.
    </div>
    <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
        <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
        <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
        <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: If I do this I get an error: "Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class"

Comment: This is not related with the problem of before, check you application.properties if one of these row is presente: 

if you are using a local instance of mysql server: spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

if you are using an in memory DB like h2:
#spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver

let me know if you solve

Comment: About the url attribute maybe you are even missing the url configuration:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_database?useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull

Comment: I added an url in the application.propeties but the authentication doesnt work anymore if I do that.

Comment: Ok...try to post your properties file. Is your mysql server running?

Comment: There is only 2 configuration that has nothing to do with my question. I am using a Datasource class and as I said everything is working fine but only If I do what you said it doesnt work.

Comment: try to add this esclusion in you datasource config class
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})